# How sensitive is androids Device ID

Tags: android

I just had a quick question that I am unable to find an answer to. I wanted to know if the device id used in android systems is sensitive information, if I was to get the device id of a user and publicize it would that be a problem to the users security in any way or form? Basically I want to know if someone was to get ones Device id what could they do with it?

Comment: What way are you using to get this "deviceId"? IMEI? Secure.ANDROID_ID? TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()? ... You should be precise to get a relevant answer.

Comment: I would ask this on security.stackexchange